# ASP.NET MVC 4 single use impersonation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, impersonation

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 application that utilizes impersonation (running as domain user), set in web.config and setup app pool to run as same user.  Within the application we use a mix of windows authentication and a custom role provider to restrict access.

A new requirement has been brought about that requires querying data from a table locked down by AD groups.  For security reasons, we cannot at our generic user to this table, or control it via custom roles.  The only way our DBA will allow this data to leave it's respective home is when it is to one of the users within the AD groups assigned.  So, I need to be able to make a call to an EF stored proc or Repo method as the current request's user.

I have tried something like the following (I hope this might clear up what I am attempting to do):

```
   [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult TestCall()
        {
        var lst = new List<Staged>();
        //Get current request user
        using (var person = ((WindowsIdentity) HttpContext.User.Identity))
        {
            //Impersonate said user
            person.Impersonate();

            //Make magics happen
            using (var db = new TestEntities())
            {
                lst.AddRange(db.up_testseccall());

            }
        }
        //Return magics, hopefully.
        return View(lst.ToArray());
        }
```

This code works fine locally, but fails miserably when tested remotely with a test account of mine.  Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The issue I'm having now is that the DB is recieving the login as 'NT Authority\Anonymous Login'
EDIT 2:
Managed to receive a 'Safe handle has been closed' exception...so that's something new.
EDIT 3:
Current connection string

**EDIT 4:
I gave up on this approach after a week of trying to get kerberos double-hop setup.  I opted for a special domain service account for handling the required transactions.**

```
<add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DATABASENAME;initial catalog=CATALOG;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: @Chriseyre2000 added error in Edits

Comment: What does your Connection Sting look like (remove any security info first).

Comment: @ErikPhilips added in Edit 3

Comment: You may need to look at using Kerberos.

Comment: In your view, what is printed if you output `<span>@System.Web.Context.Current.User.Identity.Name</span>`?

Comment: It would be my account, either domain or test.